# Create Button in random places of form C#.NET

Tags: c#

I want to create 20 buttons in random places of a form. My code is written below, but it doesn't work as I expect, some buttons drop into each other and some of them go out of form.

```
int x,y;
for (int i = 1; i <= 20; i++)
{
    Random rnd = new Random(Math.Abs(Guid.NewGuid().GetHashCode()));
    x = rnd.Next(this.Width-50);
    y = rnd.Next(this.Height-50);
    Button btn = new Button();
    btn.Location = new Point(x, y);
    this.Controls.Add(btn);
}
```

Can anyone help me find the problem in this code?

Comment: If you want the buttons not to get in top of others, you'll have to check if there is a button below the one you are going to add. For that,i would create a list of buttons and check the positions and sizes before adding a new one.

Comment: "Some buttons drop into each other" - I see no effort to detect overlap, so that is only to be expected. You should think about how to do that, and then implement your idea. This is not a site where people will implement any strange idea for you. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: can you plz correct my code ??

Comment: Try to implement one of the ideas that may be posted as answers or comments. No one will werite complete code here for anyone :)

Comment: @Salar_n1 `can you plz correct my code ?? ` SO is **not** a code-writing service. You don't have a problem with existing code, you are missing functionality and you are aware of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course they will be stacked onto each other.

You have to take into consideration the position of previously created buttons when fetching a new random position from Rand.Next(). A good way to do this would be to save such positions into Array or generate numbers beforehand and stop doing so if you got your 20 positions that match a set of conditions that in the end allow you to conclude that:

For each position in Array:

- A button of size X, Y at position x, y (left-top corner of button) will not be overlapping any other button in said array.
- Button of size X, Y at position x, y will not extend out of main window.